# Why do we use the Choose function here?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Assume two gamblers playing a series of poker games, which is independently won with prob. $p$ for player $1$ and $1-p$ for player $2$. The ultimate winner of the series is the first to win k card games.

What is $Pr[\text{a total of 7 games are played}]$, for $k=4$?

I can see that to have 7 games, we need to be tied at 3 wins for each player after 6 games. So the $$Pr[\text{a total of 7 games are played}] = Pr[\text{each player wins 3 games after 6}] = \binom{6}{3}p^3(1-p)^3 $$ I just don't understand **quietly** the use of the choose function to solve this?

**What makes this dst different from a neg. Bin. Dst?**

Comment: I know that I have 20 ways the 6 games can be won. I actually enumerated them. But I just want to learn the intuition behind the choose function in this case.

Comment: Lets call the two gamblers "A" and "B".  There are 6 games, 3 won by each player.  To find the total number of ways that could happen, you could write down 6 "A"s and then **choose** three of them to be change to "B".

Comment: (Note in passing that poker is a rather curious choice of a game to reduce to a binary "win or lose" outcome, since skill in poker is not about _how many times_ you win vs lose, but about how cheaply you can lose when you lose, vs how much you can win when you win).

Answer (score 2):

Once you know that the first player has won three games out of six, there are $\binom 63$ choices/possibilities for which three games they won.

(The second player won the others)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a negative binomial distribution because there are two *different* stopping conditions: either that the first player has won 4 games or that the second player has won 4 games. That is a more complex situation than the negative binomial distribution is made to model.